# mail script in php

Tags: php, email

I am hosting my web application(`pnpmkt.com`) from `GODADDY.com` they have given me some email account like **info@pnpmkt.com**. I want to send welcome message to new user's to their mail account in other mail servers like google, yahoo.for example,  my mail function is-

```
<?php
```

`$address = "piysuh@gmail.com";`
`$Subject = "PNP Solutions";`
`$body = "Welcome to PNP";`
`$mailsend = mail("$address", "$Subject", "$body.");`
`print("$mailsend");`
`?>`

**what other configurations are required?Any path name or server name??**

Comment: On GoDaddy severs, this should work as is.

Comment: Add `ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);` to the beginning of your test script; add `var_dump($mailsend);` to the end, and test!

Comment: @salman-it sends only txt mails what if I want to send some HTML mails means with some company logo , colored text ,...?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wrapper function I use to send emails (text or html):

```
// $Sender: Sender email
// $Recipient: Recipient email
// $Subject: Email subject
// $Detail: Plain text or HTML (should include <html> and <body> tags)
// $Type: TEXT or HTML

function sendmail( $Sender, $Recipient, $Subject, $Detail, $Type )
{
    switch ( $Type )
    {
        case "TEXT":
            $Header  = "From: $Sender\n";
            break;
        case "HTML":
            $Header  = "From: $Sender\n";
            $Header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
            $Header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
            break;
    }
    return mail( $Recipient, $Subject, $Detail, $Header );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify whether you are having trouble sending emails using this method? From what I can see, your code is good, and should operate without any problems.

I just tested this code, myself, and it works fine.

It should be noted that the `mail()` function returns TRUE on success and FALSE on failure so echoing that is not a terribly useful thing to do. (You'll just get "1" if it worked and "0" if it didn't.)

If you are wanting to include more advanced features and facilities in your emails, however, you may want to look at [PHPmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=phpmailer), which is a PHP Class allowing for the sending of HTML Emails, changing various settings like the Sender's email address and name, etc.